# Function that transforms a Matrix to different dimensions

Tags: matrices, transformation

What is the name of a function that transforms a matrix into different dimensions?

Say I have a matrix **M** of dimensions $(x,y)$ and I want to transform it to dimensions $(w,v)$.  I can accomplish this by multiplying **M** from in front and behind by matrices **A** and **B** of dimensions $(w,x)$ and $(y,v)$.  So the function would look like this.
$$ f\left(\textbf{M}\right) = \textbf{A}\textbf{M}\textbf{B} $$

What is the name of a function like that?

Comment: Little off-topic side note: the correct MathJax command for bold text is `\textbf`

Answer (score 0):

In your case it is a **linear application**, so it can be represented by a matrix as well (but of size $xy\times wv$).

Comment: References? Can't find anything under that name.

Comment: @AlexR: there are no special references: this is just a linear application on a vector space, which is in that case the space of linear applications $\Bbb R^y\to\Bbb R^x$.